# How to integrate CORS, Google Blog and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, blogs

I have a working JavaScript on a web page that `get`s my blog from a blog site and displays it in a sidebar on my web page. In other words I blog in one place, but also display my blog content in another place (my web page).

The script uses Cross Origin Sharing (CORS) and looks like this:

```
$(
  function () {
    $.get(
     'http://www.corsproxy.com/my_name.soup.io/rss/original',
     function (data) {
      var items = data.getElementsByTagName('item');
      var thoughts = $('#activity ul');
      var count = 0;
      $(items).each(function (i, e) {
        count++;
        if (count > 10) return;
        thoughts.append('<li>'
          + e.getElementsByTagName('description')[0].textContent
          + '<small>' 
          + $.timeago( new Date(e.getElementsByTagName('pubDate')[0].textContent) )
          + '</small></li>');
     });
    }, 'xml'
   );
  }
);
```

I want to move my blog to Google blogging and have an account URL that looks like this: http://my_name.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

But I think I still need to invoke CORS so that the JavaScript on the web site can cross domains to the Google site. I have tried using the Google URL directly but the script does not `get` the content.

How should I change the JavaScript so that my web page running the JavaScript will display the content from the Google blog?

As an aside: using the same JavaScript, I am able to display content (the title of the commit) from my Github account on my web page. In this case I do not use CORS; the following JavaScript works as expected:

```
$.getScript(
  '/public/bin/jquery.timeago.js',
  function () {
    $.getScript(
      '/public/bin/jquery.github-activity.js',
      function () {
        $("#gh-activity ul").githubActivityFor("my_name", { limit: 10 });
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Why does the Github `get` work without using CORS?

Can I reconfigure the `get` for the Google blog to act in the same way as `get` for my Github account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining the [code for the `githubActivityFor` call](https://github.com/rstrobl/jquery-github-activity/blob/ce0eaaf0abee707d56fcdb177fed643f7e53315c/jquery.github-activity.js#L84), we see:

```
$.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username + '/events?callback=?', function(activity) {
    ...
},
"jsonp");
```

The `"jsonp"` argument tells jQuery that that JSONP is being used here, and the resource should be loaded inside of `<script>` tag instead of fetched with Ajax. Sure enough, we we actually look at a [user's activity feed from that URL template](https://api.github.com/users/apsillers/events?callback=foobar), it's a script. jQuery can therefore perform a JSONP script load in the usual way:

- storing the callback function (i.e., the second argument) in a variable with a random, long name like `jQuery35758395`
- replacing the `?` in `callback=?` with the same value (e.g., `jQuery35758395`)
- loading the script resource in a `<script>` tag

The Github resource (like any traditional JSONP server-side endpoint) is set up to use value of the `callback` parameter in a function call in the beginning of the script (e.g., jQuery35758395({ 'some': 'data' }). When script runs, the function call is executed, and it triggers the randomly-named callback we set up before the fetch.

Turns out Blogger supports JSONP on their server already. If you visit http://foobar.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?callback=foobaz you'll see the feed data wrapped inside of a function call. To take advantage of this, simply perform your `$.get` with a `callback=?` parameter:

```
$.get(
     'http://my_name.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?callback=?',
     function (data) {
         ...
     },
     "jsonp");
```

This will automatically do JSONP behind the scenes and correctly invoke your callback function with the XML string. Unfortunately, the string won't be parsed into a DOM structure for you already, but the `jQuery` function (a.k.a., `$`) can parse the `data` string for you:

```
var feedDOM = $(data).get(1);
```

The `get` call pulls the DOM structure out of the jQuery object, but you can also keep it in the jQuery object and use jQuery functions to examine it. Alternatively, you can supply the XML string as a context argument for a jQuery selector:

```
var authorTags = $("author", data);
```

Comment: TY - am getting the basic idea. Would you go one more step and advise how to use the Blogger script in place of the 'get' request? In other words, how to change the CORS-related code to Blogger-JSONP code. Do I select the requested fields from Blogger code, store it on my server, and call it in the JavaScript? Or can I pass the requested fields to the Blogger code (at the foobar address) and then display the data on the website? I'm not sure what next steps to take here.

Comment: @JayGray I've expanded the end of my answer a little. Also, I originally forgot the add the "jsonp" argument for `dataType`; without that, it won't work!

Comment: Am not yet able to make this work. Should I open a new question with just the updated blogspot code? Or should I add my version of your advice here?

Comment: @JayGray It depends where your problem is. If you are having trouble making the `$.get` fetch anything, then you should probably update your question. If your `$.get` call is getting a result, but it's not the result you want (e.g., you're having trouble using the XML string, but you *do have* an XML string) then you should open a new question. My second code block seems to work fine if you replace `...` with `alert(data)`, for example, so I expect you're having trouble *using* the result, rather than *getting* the result (which was the original scope of this question).

Comment: I'll open a new question and notify you. The new question will have only the blogspot issue and my implementation of your advice. Will take me about 30 minutes to write it up properly.

Comment: Just posted the question: How to implement jsonp callback to integrate a Google blog on a web page?